# Can Pandas write to the same CSV file concurrently?

Tags: python, pandas

I mistakenly had two scripts running at the same time that wrote a pandas dataframe in chunks to the same CSV file. Since the CSV file was supposed to be appended, the script itself doesn't block writing to the CSV file if it already exists. I didn't catch it until it was too late.

Kinda like this:

**script1.py**

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(datachunks):
       do something
       result_df.to_csv('csvfile.csv') (in write mode for the 1st chunk, append mode for the next chunks)
```

**script2.py**

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(datachunks2):
       do something
       result_df.to_csv('csvfile.csv') (in write mode for the 1st chunk, append mode for the next chunks)
       # should have been csvfile2.csv
```

Each script takes around 12 hours to execute due to the sheer volume of data that has to be processed, and I think it's faster to separate the CSV file into two so that I get the outputs that *each* script should have given. This should work -- unless I have unintended duplicates in the file, or even lines that didn't write.

Both scripts finished without any errors, if that's relevant.

Any chance of duplicates/missing data in this `csvfile.csv`?

Comment: Probably less likely data didn't get written to the file, and more that the text got interleaved. Sounds like a big mess to untangle.

Comment: @Todd Each CSV file has a corresponding `user` column, and I know which users should be processed by which script. Interleaving shouldn't be a problem, but missing/duplicated data would. I'd only be able to use this file if I'm 100% sure there are no missing/duplicated data, given that both scripts completed writing all chunks without any errors.

Comment: what is datachunks, file, pandas dataframe, numpy array?

Comment: @irene you have a strategy for identifying and removing duplicated data? Timestamps?

Comment: @Todd I can check for duplicates (I have a column for month and day, and there should only be one row for each user per day), but not for missing data.

Comment: @Datanovice it's a dataframe

Comment: I would recommend using sqlite Db to write data however you want and then later export it to CSV while exiting the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just rerun the scripts and compare the outputs. Seems it's not promising -- I lost a lot of rows.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @irene. Maybe you can call IT and see if they backed up the data on the system and can restore your files - or maybe you have.. what is it.. time capsule..last known good config... whatever they call it turned on for the system hosting the data and there's a state you can restore to the system before the data got munged.

Comment: @Todd thankfully it isn't that serious. All the files are in my local anyway, so no IT to contact, and the correct files have been generated. My case should serve as a warning to others who want to do the same.

Comment: I have aspired to become a cautionary tale at times as well.